# How to stop user from generating more events?

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, jsr296

I am developing a java swing desktop application. The dialog form has an ok and cancel button. When the user clicks ok button the application does *some* processing. How can I stop user from clicking ok again before the event on ok button has finished executing. Also, i dont want the user to able to press the cancel button till ok has finished executed. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Enablement management is an integral part of UI logic. Action helps you doing so:

```
 Action action = new AbstractAction("myAction") {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           setEnabled(false);
           doPerform();
           setEnabled(true);
      }
 };
 button.setAction(action);
```

Beware: long running task *must not* be executed on the EDT, so this is for short-term only, to prevent the second or so click having an effect

**Edit**

just noticed that you tagged the question with jsr296, then it's even easier: you can tag a method of your presentation model as @Action and bind its enabled property to a property of the model

```
@Action (enabledProperty == "idle")
public void processOk() {
    setIdle(false);
    doStuff;
    setIdle(true);
}
```

Plus there is support (much debated, but useable) for Tasks: basically SwingWorker with fine-grained beanified life-cycle support

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable all the controls, then I'd suggest using a `GlassPane`. See here for more info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to disable the button just after clicking it , and when the action performed is complete then re-enable it.

Comment: But what is the case when there are many buttons on my dialog, i will have to continuously enable and disable and it might become a maintenance nightmare. There should be a more graceful way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable your button like yourButton.setEnabled(false); during your processing method and enable it again when it finishes.

Comment: please see the comment to pheromix,  I have added above

Comment: actually .. no, don't fiddle with button state directly, instead configure it with an Action and do the state management there

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you want is something like a [waiting cursor](http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/wait_cursor.shtml).